# What does third symbol in "rw-" file mode mean in OS X ls manual page?

Tags: macos, file-permissions, ls, documentation

I have trouble understanding `ls`'s manual regarding a file that has `rw-` mode. Here's the quote:

> 1. If **`r`**, the **file is readable**; if **`−`**, it is not readable.
> 2. If **`w`**, the file is writable; if **`−`**, it is not writable.
> 3. The first of the following that applies:
>
>    **`S`**     If in the owner permissions, the file is not executable and set-user-ID mode is set.  If in the group permissions, the file is not executable and set-group-ID mode is set.
>
>    **`s`**     If in the owner permissions, the file is executable and set-user-ID mode is set.  If in the group permissions, the file is executable and setgroup-ID mode is set.
>
>    **`x`**     The file is executable or the directory is searchable.
>
>    **`−`**     The file is **neither readable**, writable, executable, nor set-user-ID nor set-group-ID mode, nor sticky.

In particular, it seem that two sections in bold contradict each other: according to the first one, since the mode begins with `r`, the file is readable, but according to the last one, the file is **not** readable. But, obviously, that is not the case.

So, what does that third section mean about file being "neither readable, writable..."?

---

**Bibliography**

- apple.com seems to be the source of the text quoted above. 
  [This](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/ls.1.html) is the man page
  (for OS X version 10.9, titled "BSD General Commands Manual"),
  and [this](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6462497) is a discussion page that quotes it.
- [ss64.com](http://ss64.com/osx/ls.html) also has a copy of the OS X `ls` man page.
- [tuhs.org](http://minnie.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=4.4BSD/usr/share/man/cat1/ls.0) has the 4.4 BSD man page. 
  Beware: it uses `wwoorrdd` for bold and `_w_o_r_d` for underline.
- [freebsd.org](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ls) has the FreeBSD 10.1 man page, dated March 15, 2013.
- unix.com has a copy of the bad page
  under the man-page/[freebsd](http://www.unix.com/man-page/freebsd/1/ls) directory (for FreeBSD 11.0).  Note that
  they also have a copy of the correct page under man-page/[posix](http://www.unix.com/man-page/posix/1posix/ls).
- The "A+ 4 Real StudyExam4Less Computer Series"
  contains the text quoted in the question,
  plus a couple of paragraphs about `T` and `t`, but not the entire man page. 
  It is talking about OS X.  You can see pages
  from two slightly different versions (editions?) of this book
  on books.google.com [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=sZj4xYW739YC&pg=PA468&lpg=PA468&dq=%22The+file+is+neither+readable,+writable,+executable,+nor%22&source=bl&ots=0xs2q3zcfL&sig=3ixseQS-0iu0uROz1wM3yIkNCnU&hl=en&sa=X&ei=-SiLVZzXNYy0-QGRs7ngCA&ved=0CCsQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=%22The%20file%20is%20neither%20readable%2C%20writable%2C%20executable%2C%20nor%22&f=false) and [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=pVbXRbpzthkC&pg=PA487&lpg=PA487&dq=%22The+file+is+neither+readable,+writable,+executable,+nor%22&source=bl&ots=nipFDnAvX2&sig=lVArkxsh5OW7QBGC36-L9vYhy4g&hl=en&sa=X&ei=-SiLVZzXNYy0-QGRs7ngCA&ved=0CDAQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=%22The%20file%20is%20neither%20readable%2C%20writable%2C%20executable%2C%20nor%22&f=false).  
  [certiguide.com](http://www.certiguide.com/apfr/cg_apfr_ListingFilesandDirectoriesls.htm) seems to be quoting them.
- [stevens.edu](https://www.cs.stevens.edu/~jschauma/631/ls.pdf) is a PDF file containing the BSD
  (General Commands Manual) version of `ls(1)`. 
  It is dated September 24, 2011.

Better:

- [quora.com](http://www.quora.com/How-should-I-read-the-output-of-ls-l) has the same text,
  but with the formatting (indentation) corrupted so badly
  that the meaning is ambiguous.

Better yet:

- [cyberciti.biz](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/explain-the-nine-permissions-bits-on-files) and [hurricanelabs.com](https://hurricanelabs.com/blog/unix-file-permissions) have the same text,
  but with the indentation corrected to the point that one could argue
  that it's essentially OK.  But they're both still really a mess.

Comment: Moved from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31021900/what-does-third-symbol-in-rw-file-mode-mean

Comment: rwx  -- read/write/execute

Comment: @emirjonb I'm not sure how this answers my question.

Comment: Just a kindly remind, I dont know what are you going to achieve, but if you are just worrying permission problem, you can always `chomd 777`, which mean you have full control (read/write/execute) to the file/directory.

Comment: Please don't post the same question on multiple Stack Exchange sites simultaneously.  ([SU] and [SO] are both Stack Exchange sites.)  As it happens, this question *belongs* here and not on Stack Overflow.

Comment: You're not reading the second bold quote properly.  That sentence begins with a **minus sign** (or hyphen), and is explaining what it means.

Comment: @sawdust According to this manual excerpt, a `rw-` file is simultaneously readable (`r`), writable (`w`) and neither readable nor writable (`-`).

Comment: Where is this "maunal excerpt" from?  I cannot find this quoted text in the Linux man pages for `ls`.

Comment: @sawdust it's from OS X.

Comment: @Bilo: Please do not tell people to do that.  Not only is it (potentially) a massive security vulnerability, but it clobbers setuid/setgid/sticky bits, so `sudo chmod 777 $(which sudo)` will lock you out of the root account on systems that disable root login.

Comment: rw- means the file is readable, writable, but not executable.

Comment: 1. position is for readable: yes/no
2. position is for writable: yes/no
3. position is for executable: yes/no
if there is a hyphen (-) it is a no

Comment: @CML I don't think that you read the question.

Comment: Could you add a link with the source of this man page? ls elsewhere use a different wording.

Comment: @Braiam: I added links to a few copies of the `ls` man page.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This answer was previously posted on Stack Exchange, before I noticed the question was being moved.

Each numbered point in your quote applies in turn to each of the three characters.

> If the **first** character is 'r', the file is **readable**
>
> If the **second** character is 'w', the file is **writable**
>
> If the **third** character is 'x/s/S', the file has the **executable** and/or **set-userid/setgroupid** property as appropriate
>
> If the character is '-', then the file does not have that property.

The first three characters (after the directory identifier) apply to **user** permissions, the second three to **group** permissions, and the third to everyone else.

Comment: OK, this is a good answer to the question, “What does third symbol in `rw-` file mode mean?”  But the real question is, “How should this OS X `ls(1)` man page be understood?” and the answer is: “It can’t be; it’s garbled.”  The above post, which quotes and/or paraphrases a correct, coherent `ls(1)` man page, does not answer the question about the OS X man page.

Comment: It is still a great answer; while your answer is technically correct, this one is the most helpful to a random person that would google this man page in the future.

Comment: Yes, but the question "What does the output from `ls` mean?" is much more thoroughly answered at [What do the fields in `ls -al` output mean?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/103114/23408) on Unix & Linux Stack Exchange.  Also, of course, anybody who Googled such a question would find the millions of good, clear sources on the web, including the non-OS X, non-BSD versions of `ls(1)`

Answer (score 9):

You're right — it doesn't make sense. 
It looks like some sort of copy & paste error
(although I see that it appears on multiple sites on the web.)

Comment: The (Free)BSD [man page](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ls) has that wording too.

Comment: this is not a copy & paste error: checkout the answer from rojomoke

Comment: What’s your point?  rojomoke’s answer presents a coherent explanation of the classic nine-character representation of the mode bits — an explanation that is different from the incoherent one presented in the question.  I believe that it’s quite possible that some tech writer at Apple drastically reformatted something he didn’t really understand, and corrupted the meaning in the process.

Comment: The last line would make more sense were it not indented, because the - does represent an absence of a value, but indented the way it is suggests that it's part of the description of item #3, which describes the third symbol of each group.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the point of @Max's question — although, if the last line were not indented, then paragraphs 1 and 2 would be redundant, because they also specify conditions under which **`-`** appears.

Comment: Looks like it goes back as far as [4.4BSD](http://minnie.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=4.4BSD/usr/share/man/cat1/ls.0) . The 4.3-Reno man page doesn't have this.

Answer (score -3):

When changing permissions on a file it is possible to indicate two permissions with a simple rw- or wx- meaning that BOTH r AND w are to be set to NO. In the second example BOTH w AND x are set to NO.

You could also indicate r+w- to set READ to YES and WRITE to NO.
Or rx+ for setting Read AND Execute to YES.

Comment: I'm not sure that this is relevant to the question I asked.

Comment: I'm not sure that this is relevant to this planet.     :-)    ⁠

Comment: `chmod` arguments are not formatted the same way as `ls -l` outputs.